# Site recommendation for Grandfather clock repair

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I bought a grandfather clock and I am trying to figure out how to get it working (seems in good condition).

Is there a SE site for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say the closest one would be [diy.se](https://diy.stackexchange.com), though you would need to check their help center, to see what is and is not on topic.

Comment: Hammers and clocks normally don't go well together ...

Comment: @rene - actually... most mechanical clock has a component that's is called a hammer.

Comment: And I did buy it to improve my home. They are pretty liberal on that SE site so I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no site for time pieces on SE.  I actually made a proposal to encompass anything about time pieces a month or so back, but it was removed for "reasons of moderation" after about 3-4 days, even though there was some slight activity on it.  If you make a proposal for this on Area 51, I'll follow it.

Comment: I might just do that. I will ping you if I do. Thanks